# Javascript works in Chrome but not IE or Firefox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, scripting, google-chrome

I am using Javascript within an HTML file to expand and collapse elements of the file.

This is the script:

```
function toggleBlock(pstrID){
  var myDiv = document.getElementById('d' + pstrID);
  if (myDiv){
    if (myDiv.style.display == 'none'){
      showBlock(pstrID);
    } else{
      hideBlock(pstrID);
    }
  }
}
function showBlock(pstrID){
  var myDiv = document.getElementById('d' + pstrID);
  if (myDiv){
    myDiv.style.display = 'block';
    var myImage = document.getElementById('i' + pstrID);
    if (myImage){
      myImage.src = 'arrowdown.gif';
      myImage.alt = 'Hide';
    }
    if (document.location.href.indexOf('mk:@') == 0)
      myDiv.innerHTML = myDiv.innerHTML;
  }
}
function hideBlock(pstrID){
  var myDiv = document.getElementById('d' + pstrID);
  if (myDiv){
    myDiv.style.display = 'none';
    var myImage = document.getElementById('i' + pstrID);
    if (myImage){
      myImage.src = 'arrowright.gif';
      myImage.alt = 'Show';
    }
    if (document.location.href.indexOf('mk:@') == 0)
      myDiv.innerHTML = myDiv.innerHTML;
  }
}
```

When I call the script, I use the following:

```
<a id="h7217" class="expandingblocktemplate" title="" href="javascript:toggleBlock('7217')">
```

- In Chrome everything works fine.
- In IE, clicking the link leads to a different window (address shown is javascript:toggleBlock('7217') obviously, the number depends on the link that's clicked) and the error "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage".
- In Firefox, a new tab appears and the Error Console says:
  Error: toggleBlock is not defined
  Source File: javascript:toggleBlock('7217')
  Line: 1

Answer (score 1):

just add

```
      return false ;
```

after the toggleBlock call.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to Furqan's solution:

You should never trigger JavaScript in the `href` attribute. It's a non-standard method that easily leads to errors, especially if you don't know what you are doing. Use `onclick` instead and put a valid URL in the `href` attribute for non-script users, or use `href="#"` if you don't don't care about non-script users.

```
<a id="h7217" class="expandingblocktemplate" title="" onclick="toggleBlock('7217');" href="noscript.html">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggleBlock('7217')">
```

JavaScript:

```
function toggleBlock(pstrID) {
    var block = document.getElementById('d' + pstrID),
        img = document.getElementById('i' + pstrID);

    if ( block && img ) {    
        if ( block.style.display === 'none' ) {
            block.style.display = 'block';
            img.src ='arrowdown.gif';
            img.alt = 'Hide'; 
        } else {
            block.style.display = 'none';
            img.src = 'arrowright.gif';
            img.alt = 'Show';      
        }   

        if ( document.location.href.indexOf('mk:@') === 0 ) {
            block.innerHTML = block.innerHTML;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```